# edit names in phylogenetic tree in newick format

Tags: linux, shell, sed, perl

I have a phylogenetic tree in newick format, and I would like to remove some fragments of the name of the taxa,

```
1_[genus_specie_1]_characters:0.2654682758,(((((((((((((((2_[genus_specie_2]_characters:0.0379334280,54_[genus_specie_2]_characters:0.0605802067)/1/100:0.0121248674,(3_[genus_specie_3]_characters:0.0206432295,4_[genus_specie_4]_characters:0.0141250479)/1/100:0.0647820408)/1/100:0.0235327264,30_[genus_specie_5]_characters
```

I would like to remove the fragments out of the square brackets, for example

```
genus_specie_1:0.2654682758,(((((((((((((((genus_specie_2:0.0379334280,genus_specie_2:0.0605802067)/1/100:0.0121248674,(genus_specie_3:0.0206432295,genus_specie_4:0.0141250479)/1/100:0.0647820408)/1/100:0.0235327264,genus_specie_5
```

I have tried with one liner perl to remove all square brackets

```
perl -i -pe 'y/[]//d' file.nwk
```

and I have also tried whit the next sed command

```
sed 's/[[:alnum:]_]*\[\([[:alnum:]_]*\)\][[:alnum:]_]*/\1/g'
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: `sed 's/[[:alnum:]_]*\[\([[:alnum:]_]*\)\][[:alnum:]_]*/\1/g' <<<'1_[genus_specie_1]_characters:0.2654682758,(((((((((((((((2_[genus_specie_2]_characters:0.0379334280,54_[genus_specie_2]_characters:0.0605802067)/1/100:0.0121248674,(3_[genus_specie_3]_characters:0.0206432295,4_[genus_specie_4]_characters:0.0141250479)/1/100:0.0647820408)/1/100:0.0235327264,30_[genus_specie_5]_characters'` produces *exactly* the output you wanted. So what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

perl regexes are good here:

```
$ initial='1_[genus_specie_1]_characters:0.2654682758,(((((((((((((((2_[genus_specie_2]_characters:0.0379334280,54_[genus_specie_2]_characters:0.0605802067)/1/100:0.0121248674,(3_[genus_specie_3]_characters:0.0206432295,4_[genus_specie_4]_characters:0.0141250479)/1/100:0.0647820408)/1/100:0.0235327264,30_[genus_specie_5]_characters'
$ expected='genus_specie_1:0.2654682758,(((((((((((((((genus_specie_2:0.0379334280,genus_specie_2:0.0605802067)/1/100:0.0121248674,(genus_specie_3:0.0206432295,genus_specie_4:0.0141250479)/1/100:0.0647820408)/1/100:0.0235327264,genus_specie_5'

$ result=$( perl -pe 's/\d+_\[(.+?)\]_.*?(?=:|$)/$1/g' <<<"$initial" )

$ [[ $result = $expected ]] && echo yes
yes
```

This uses non-greedy quantifiers (`.*?`), and a look-ahead (`(?=:|$)`)